# Implicit animation on CALayer "contents" property

Tags: ios, cocoa, core-animation

According to the core animation documentation, setting the layer contents should trigger an implicit 0.25 animation that will transition between the new and old images.
I also see many places where people are asking how to remove this implicit animation but for some reason when I try this on my project, I get an instant swap of images.
Reading some more into the documention I saw this code snipped:

```
- (id<CAAction>)actionForLayer:(CALayer *)theLayer
                        forKey:(NSString *)theKey {
    CATransition *theAnimation=nil;

    if ([theKey isEqualToString:@"contents"]) {

        theAnimation = [[CATransition alloc] init];
        theAnimation.duration = 1.0;
        theAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
        theAnimation.type = kCATransitionPush;
        theAnimation.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
    }
    return theAnimation;
}
```

Which implies that "contents" is not implicitly animated.

I would be very interested to understand this better.

Comment: What are you not understanding?

Comment: Is it supposed to be animated? If not, why don't I see this?

Comment: Does it work if you explicitly animate with that transition?

Comment: @EyalRedler It does indeed animate implicitly, although it can be hard to see. The most common reason this does not work is that the layer having its contents changed is backed by a UIView. In this case, implicit layer animations are disabled. If this is not the case, please show the code you are using that does not animate implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'm copying some code from an app of mine. First I usually get CATransition not with alloc..init.. but using +animation. Second I'm not seeing that you are adding the transition to a layer. Third I'm not sure that CATransition are implicitly animated, CALayer properties yes.

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 1;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype = slideCATransitionCompareTable[ arc4random() % 4]; //to get a random subtype 
    [self.slideShowReceiptImageView.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
```

Comment: The action isn't explicitly added to a layer because it is created inside `actionForLayer:forKey:`

Comment: Well good point, don't know. The method 'actionForLayer:forKey:' is a delegate method of the protocol CALayerDelgate, you are right..

Comment: Thanks! This is the only way I could achieve "contents" animation.